# Fatal error "Undefined Method Facebook::get_user()"

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I am seeing this error "`Fatal error: Call to undefined method Facebook::get_user()`" while i am using new php-sdk

Answer (score 4):

The method name is `getUser()` not `get_user()`